# Passing data between components VueJS2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a parent component, it receives a large json from the server, I need to parse it and pass it to the child components.

child components are connected like

```
  <child-comp />
```

i need to pass `res.data` from server json to child comp to use it in rendering and in methods
How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your data as a prop like this :

```
<child-comp :myData="res.data" />
```

And in you're child component define the prop like this :

```
props: {
  myData: Object
},
```

See more in vue doc : https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html

Comment: How can I use it in comp?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data through Vue props as Adri answered.

or if you'd like to save a state to access data in multiple components, I'd suggest [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/).